# Проверка n с помощью cout

Tags: c++, вывод, операторы, тернарный-оператор, приоритет

```
int n;
cin >> n;
cout << (n == 2) ? "YES" : "NO";
```

при запуске этой программы, если n = 2 выводится 1 иначе 0, я хочу чтобы вместо 1 или 0 выводилось YES или NO. Как это сделать используя только cout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользоваться таблицей приоритетов и переписать правильно  -

```
cout << (n == 2 ? "YES" : "NO");
```